# Why does my DHTML menu have huge layout issues in IE7?

Tags: css, menu, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, dhtml

This one's got me stumped. Usually with a little CSS juggling here and there I am able to solve most IE7 CSS bugs, but not this one!

Head on over to [the example page](http://www.webfactory.co.za/rodwell/) and view it in IE7, you will soon see that when mousing over the (vertical) drop down menu on the left of the page, it opens the sub menu WAY over to the right. I have pulled every last hair out!

If it helps, the menu was made with **'Sothink DHTML Menu 9'**

As always, all replies are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sothink is not the greatest solution, try this:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/